# Where can I keep settings data for a reusable app

Tags: django

**Django=3.1**

I'd like to push some utilites of mine, template tags, filters etc. to a reusable app.
But this app will needs a huge amount of settings. Maybe 100-200 lines.

I'm thinking of placing a file called something "my_omnibus.py" next to project's settings.py

Is a good idea? If it is, could you tell me how to import that file into the reusable app if the name of the project may change.
If it is not, where can I keep the constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app's root directory, create a `settings.py` and dump all settings there. In that app, use relative imports e.g. `from .settings import SETTING_A`.

You shouldn't create settings next to project's `settings.py` module because those settings are only relevant to one app. You should only do such a thing only if those settings are going to be used by all apps (an example would be celery application configuration).